# jqGrid - Delete issue

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have simple JqGrid

```
  $j("#gridTemp").jqGrid({
    jsonReader: {
        id: 'AppID' + 'Name',
        repeatitems: false
    },
    url: GetData,
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ['Col1', 'Col2'],
    colModel: [
                { name: 'Col1'},
              { name: 'Col2'}
            ],
    rowNum: 10,
    autowidth: true,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    pager: '#pager1',
    }).navGrid('#pager1', { edit: false, add: false, del: true, search: false }, {}, {}, { url: DeleteAddress });
```

}

and trying to get delete button click event

```
$j('#del_gridTemp').click(function () { 
        alert($j('#gridTemp').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow')); 
    });
```

for some reason its not working. Any help appriciated.

Comment: What are you trying to delete? A row? A column? The grid?

Comment: Do you want to have a notification *before* the list of selected ids will be sent to the server (POSTed to the URL `DeleteAddress`) or you want do same actions after the server delete the items and jqGrid receive the server confirmation? The current code in the `$j('#del_gridTemp').click` handle has no sense. So if you describe what you really want I can recommend you the way how you can implement this.

Comment: I want to send all the selected Ids to backend. Before that just trying to display the selected IDs. As mentioned earlier, when I click the small trash icon in the JqGrid, it not calling $j('#del_gridTemp').click function.

Comment: Please use @Oleg in the comment if you answer me (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/147495) for more information). You should follow the same rule if you answer to any other comment. To your question: you make some simple error in your code. I'll post you a demo where the same code to work and you will compare it with your version to fine the error.

Comment: @Oleg im trying to find that simple error..anyway appreciated your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is the error, but I hope [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Yass.htm) will help you.

First you use `selarrrow` parameter, so I suppose you want to have multiselect grid. So I added `multiselect: true` parameter in the code. You original code with `$('#del_gridTemp').click(function () {...});` works in my demo. I modified just the text of the alerts. If you for example select rows having "test4", "test2", "test12" you will see first the message like

[image]

after you click "OK" button and then "Delete" button in the confirmation dialog you will see the next message

[image]

from the [onclickSubmit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events2) callback function which I recommend you to use. To code looks like

```
$("#gridTemp").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {refreshstate: 'current', add: false, edit: false, del: true},
    {},
    {},
    { url: '/DeleteAddress',
        onclickSubmit: function (options, postdata) {
            alert('in onclickSubmit: postdata=' + postdata);
            return { myData: 'Hello'};
        }});
```

Inside of `onclickSubmit` method I show additionally how to append the information which will be sent with additional information.

I don't have any server code under the URL '/DeleteAddress', but in any tools like Fiddler of Firebug you will be able to the the format of data which will be posted. It's the data in x-www-form-urlencoded form:

```
myData=Hello&oper=del&id=4%2C2%2C12
```

which are in decoded form:

```
myData=Hello
oper=del
id=4,2,12
```

I think it should be close to what you need.

Comment: that works. thank you. But still i couldn't figure out the problem in my code.

Comment: @Yass: You are welcome! I reproduced exactly your code and it works. Moreover I don't recommend you to use `$('#del_gridTemp').click` directly. The usage of `onclickSubmit` is better. It will be called only if the user not only click the delete button, but confirm the deletion. You can also use [navButtonAdd](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) to create the same button as "Delete" and have full control in the `onClickButton` callback.

Answer (score 0):

See jqGrid methods [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods). You can delete rows like this:

```
$('#the_button').click(function () {
    //get selected Ids returns like: ["1", "2", "3"]
    var selectedIds = $('#gridTemp').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');

    //iterate over each id and delete the corresponding row
    $.each(selectedIds, function (index) {
        $('#gridTemp').jqGrid('delRowData', selectedIds[index]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, the problem is     $('#the_button')     .In my case its not firing the event when I click the button.

Comment: @Yass Can you gives us more of an explanation of what's going on then? Without that or more code it's difficult to tell.

Comment: Its very simple, when you click the small trash icon in the JqGrid, it has to call the $('#del_GridID).click event right?. In my case, its not firing the event. I have given the full code in my question.